# How can I indent parts of a Views field?

Tags: views, entities, theming

I have a content/node View listing several node fields in an unformated list. The fields are displayed inline since they combine to make a message to users; on their own the fields don't mean much.

[image]
[image]

As you can see there are 3 fields above; user picture, user name, and the comment body. I have marked the order and the areas of the 3 separate span classes. The problem of course is that when field 3 has more than one line of text the subsequent lines are not indented enough and overlap field 1. I have tried using margin-left and padding-left in combination with the text-indent property, but since field 3 is inline the CSS only ends up indenting the first line instead of the lines after the first as I need. I can display field 3 as a block and this does allow me to have better control, however it places the field on a separate row, and as mentioned previously I need the fields to be displayed inline so that they combine to make a message. In other words, if you see the red line below I would like the field 3 text to wrap and indent in a way that it stays to the right of the red line for lines 2 and after.

[image]

So it would end up looking something like below, but of course with the beginning of the lines not clipped.

[image]

The only thing I can think of is having 2 copies of field 3, both of which are trimmed. Therefore the first copy would be trimmed to only show 1 line and the second would be trimmed to show everything after the first line, however the problem is that I'm not sure how to trim the beginning of a field. So how can this be achieved?

Comment: This is CSS work, not drupal. For Drupal there's way to make table: 2 columns : image | Name + Body. Name should be excluded and cleared wrapper div. and shown on Body.

Comment: It is relevant to Drupal because I am applying CSS to Views results. If I was not using Drupal and hand coding I could simply divide my content up into as manny div/spans as I like and it would be much more straight forward to control. Also, could you please explain how creating a table would allow my to control the indentation of the text after the first line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Put the class clearfix as the row class (format->settings). If your
   theme does not have [clearfix](https://www.google.co.za/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCgQFjAC&url=http%3A%2F%2Fnicolasgallagher.com%2Fmicro-clearfix-hack%2F&ei=KA7CU7fMFcOU0AWsp4DACA&usg=AFQjCNGdVDpGBJyklUh9C0KofBvYtufMBA&bvm=bv.70810081,d.d2k) defined, define it yourself.
2. Hide the output of the other two fields (click on the field in views
   form and you will see this setting 'exclude from display').
3. Create a global: Custom text field and make sure it is the last
   field in the views list of fields.
4. Rewrite results -> rewrite the output of this global
   text field, and from the replacement patterns select field 2 and 3
   as tokens. Also add a class for that field in style settings such as
   'align-block'. Define it as follows:

   align-block {
   overflow:hidden;
   }

in your css file.

1. Add a class to your image field such as 'float-left'. Define it as follows:

   float-left {
   float:left;
   }

in your css file.

Comment: Thanks for trying J. Reynolds, but I am not attempting to hide the overflow I am trying to indent the text after the first line. Perhaps this can only be done by splitting my field 3 into 2 separate fields and controlling each independently through CSS.

Comment: And this is how you indent the text. Don't be misled by obvious meaning of overflow. Check out this good post about it. [CSS: Clearing Floats with Overflow](http://webdesignerwall.com/tutorials/css-clearing-floats-with-overflow)